# Why does Elise take damage from Fizz's ultimate during Rappel?

Tags: league-of-legends

I noticed that if Fizz tags Elise with his ultimate, then even if Elise casts Rappel, she will still take damage! I thought that Elise becomes untargetable during Rappel. Why does she still get hit?

Comment: well... she doesn't

Comment: Close voters: this question is abundantly clear. It's asking about a mechanic, and while it was lacking in grammar, there was only one possible interpretation. I couldn't help but notice none of you have any points in this tag, so I suggest [reviewing this meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195).

Comment: voting to reopen.

Comment: Thank U. Anyway -_- but it's my first Q in this site..

Answer (score 4):

To be more clear, untargetable only means new effects cannot be placed on you.  Anything already on your character (DoTs, Zilean bombs, Fizz fish, etc) will still apply.  Works like that for Vladimir as well.  If you want a character that actually becomes invincible, try Kayle or Lissandra.

Answer (score 1):

You give the answer yourself. During Rappel, she is "untargetable" which means that all damage taken will still apply. Ignite will still tick during Rappel. On the other hand, "invulnerable", the effect given by Zhonya's Hourglass, does stop the damage.

Comment: That's not really true.
If you have zilean bomb on fizz, with the right timing, you can cancel the damage with his E, which is untargetable...
Same, while playing fizz against elise, she could just not take any damage. So maybe there is a bug now but I have never seen it.